# What does Tensorflow LSTM return?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm writing a German->English translator using an encoder/decoder pattern, where the encoder connects to the decoder by passing the state output of its last LSTM layer
as the input state of the decoder's LSTM.

I'm stuck, though, because I don't know how to interpret the output of the encoder's LSTM.  A small example:

```
tensor = tf.random.normal( shape = [ 2, 2, 2 ])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True )
result = lstm( ( tensor )
print( "result:\n", result )
```

Executing this in Tensorflow 2.0.0 produces:

```
result:
[
<tf.Tensor: id=6423, shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.05060377, -0.00500009, -0.10052835],
        [ 0.01804499,  0.0022153 ,  0.01820258]],
       [[ 0.00813384, -0.08705016,  0.06510869],
        [-0.00241707, -0.05084776,  0.08321179]]], dtype=float32)>,
<tf.Tensor: id=6410, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.01804499,  0.0022153 ,  0.01820258],
       [-0.00241707, -0.05084776,  0.08321179]], dtype=float32)>,
<tf.Tensor: id=6407, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.04316794,  0.00382055,  0.04829971],
       [-0.00499733, -0.10105743,  0.1755833 ]], dtype=float32)>
]
```

The result is a list of three tensors.  The first appears to be the output of all
hidden states, as selected by `return_sequences=True`.  My question is:  **What is the interpretation of the second and third Tensors in** `result`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An LSTM cell in Keras gives you three outputs:

- an output state `o_t` (1st output)
- a hidden state `h_t` (2nd output)
- a cell state `c_t` (3rd output)

and you can see an LSTM cell here:
[image: LSTM input/output diagram]

The output state is generally passed to any upper layers, but not to any layers to the right. You would use this state when predicting your final output.

The cell state is information that is transported from previous LSTM cells to the current LSTM cell. When it arrives in the LSTM cell, the cell decides whether information from the cell state should be deleted, i.e. we will "forget" some states. This is done by a forget gate: This gate takes the current features `x_t` as an input and the hidden state from the previous cell `h_{t-1}`. It outputs a vector of probabilities that we multiply with the last cell state `c_{t-1}`. After determining what information we want to forget, we update the cell state with the input gate. This gate takes the current features `x_t` as an input and the hidden state from the previous cell `h_{t-1}` and produces an input which is added to the last cell state (from which we have already forgotten information). This sum is the new cell state `c_t`.
To get the new hidden state, we combine the cell state with a hidden state vector, which is again a vector of probabilities that determines which information from the cell state should be kept and which should be discarded.

As you have correctly interpreted, the first tensor is the output of all hidden states.

The second tensor is the hidden output, i.e. $h_t$, which acts as the short-term memory of the neural network
The third tensor is the cell output, i.e. $c_t$, which acts as the long-term memory of the neural network

In the [keras-documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) it is written that

```
whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm(inputs)
```

Unfortunately they do not use the term hidden and cell state. In their terminology the memory state is the short-term memory, i.e. the hidden state. The carry state is carried through all LSTM cells, i.e. it is the cell state.

We can also verify this using the [source code of the LSTM cell](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L957-L1288), where a forward step is given by

```
def step(cell_inputs, cell_states):
    """Step function that will be used by Keras RNN backend."""
    h_tm1 = cell_states[0]   #previous memory state
    c_tm1 = cell_states[2]   #previous carry state

    z = backend.dot(cell_inputs, kernel)
    z += backend.dot(h_tm1, recurrent_kernel)
    z = backend.bias_add(z, bias)

    z0, z1, z2, z3 = array_ops.split(z, 4, axis=1)

    i = nn.sigmoid(z0)
    f = nn.sigmoid(z1)
    c = f * c_tm1 + i * nn.tanh(z2)
    o = nn.sigmoid(z3)

    h = o * nn.tanh(c)
    return h, [h, c]
```

From the formulas we can easily see that the first and second outputs are the output/hidden state and the third output is the cell state. and it also states that they name the hidden state "memory state" and the cell state "carry state"

Comment: Excellent explanation. Should be added to the official Keras doc