# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60, 5), found shape=(None, 60, 7)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, prediction

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 60, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 5)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 70, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 5)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 90, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 5)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 140, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 5)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units =1))
regressor.summary()


regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='mean_absolute_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size =50)[enter image description here][1]
```

On running this code ; the value error raised while I was preparing my model for prediction . Help me to rectify it

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-535f5f5c29a7> in <module>()
----> 1 regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size =50)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
    66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    68     finally:
    69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
  1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
  1148             else:
  1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
       return step_function(self, iterator)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
       outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
       outputs = model.train_step(data)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
       y_pred = self(x, training=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
       raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

   ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60, 5), found shape=(None, 60, 7)
```

On running the code ; I came across this error on my python interpretor.
Let me know the correct compatibility!

Comment: Are you sure that you have to add input_shape to every layer? As far as I know, this should be done only for the first layer

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty much says it all. The first LSTM layer in your model expects a batch of time series, each having 60 timesteps and **5** features per timestep, but somehow you fed it a batch of time series each having 60 steps and **7** features. You might check your `X_train.shape[2]` to see if it is 7.

Also, the way you're using the output of LSTM layers is incorrect. You might want to go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970519/what-does-tensorflow-lstm-return) and [official tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) to see what are the outputs of a LSTM layer with `return_sequences` set to `True`.